# extract list from dropdown menu from any website

Tags: dropdown

Im visiting a website ..
it has a dropdown menu of all the plants names
when I select some specific plant
below the scientific name of it display
how can I get that list of all plants with scientific name of each one from that website

I managed to take all the list of plants but I dont know how to get them with thier scientific name
something like this
name of plant => sientific name

Comment: Including a link to the specific site would be helpful. There is insufficient information in the question to answer it as it currently is.